# Comparing and extracting similar strings from 2 arrays in java, double words not compared

Tags: java, arrays, string

I know that similar question was asked before, however I cannot find the answer to my problem!

I am comparing arrays and extracting similarities with the HashSet.

```
final String[] abc = nlp_text.split(" ");
final String[] xyz = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xyz);

    final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(String a : abc) set.add(a.toLowerCase());
    final HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    for(String a : xyz) set1.add(a.toLowerCase());
    set.retainAll(set1);
    String[] pqr= {};
    pqr = set.toArray(pqr);
```

This works on single word strings, however does not work on double word strings. For instance, strings "John" and "Doe" will be recognised separately, but "John Doe" will not.

any idea why?

UPDATE: as was pointed out to me it was the nlp_text.split(" ") issue. However, when I tried splitting it with "," and then all other marks, it would not recognise any of the strings. return would be just blank... help, pls!

Comment: `This works on single word strings, however does not work on double word strings.` - It is because you are splitting on `" "` (space). Post the content of the file so that one can suggest you how to split the text data.

Comment: oh, i see!! thanks!! will play around...

Answer (score 2):

`nlp_text.split(" ");` splits the words, therefore your "John Doe" String becomes two seperate "John" and "Doe" Strings. I recommend split the nlp_text with commas for example, so that your two word Strings are counted as one String.

Answer (score 1):

When you define abc:

```
final String[] abc = nlp_text.split(" ");
final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for(String a : abc) set.add(a.toLowerCase());
```

you are doing a split by " " so "abc" is only going to have one word strings, so "set" is only going to have one word strings, so later when you do the retain.

```
set.retainAll(set1);
```

This means "set" can only retain one word strings, because it only have one word strings.